# Android MapView: disable pan when dragging on overlay

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview

in my Android app I have a LinearLayout partially over a MapView and dragging on the layout causes the map to pan.

How can this be avoided? Of course I can't disable pan because dragging on the map itself should move it. See this screenshot for clarification:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Dunno if it's relevant (don't think so): both MapView and LinearLayout are inside a RelativeLayout.

Thanks,
Maurizio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your `LinearLayout` be clickable? Either `android:clickable="true"` in XML or `setClickable(true);` in code.

Comment: no, it's not: I've even tried to explicitly set clickable="false" but it didn't helped

Comment: sorry did you mean I need to set to TRUE? adding clickable="true" solved the issue! PS: setting focus does not matter

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain Why the linear layout is partially over the Map View? You can arrange it in such a way that linear layout not overlapping map view.

Set the focusable and clickable property of linear layout to true